# Add stringA or stringB to values in column based on condition

Tags: r

I have a data table "dates" such as:

```
dates <- data.frame(date1=c("2015","1998","2000","1991"),
        date2=c("98","00","18","92"))
dates <- mutate_if(dates,is.factor,as.character)
```

Where the values in "dates" are of class -char

I want to make "date2" a 4-digit number. For this I would like the following condition:

- If "date2" starts with 9 add a 19 before the value
- If "date2" starts with anything else add a 20

I have done a lot of research but I cannot find how to add a string to an already existing string by using a conditional

Afterthought: How can we deal with "NA" values so it does not assign a "19" or "20" to "NA´s"

Comment: so `89` will become `2089`...?

Comment: Ideally not. I will be able to distinguish between assigning it years up until 2018...so not 2089.

Comment: @johnnydoe your condition in original post don't reflect that

Comment: `with(dates, ifelse(grepl("^9", date2), paste0("19", date2), paste0("20", date2)))`

Comment: Another option: `as.POSIXlt(as.Date(dates$date2, "%y"))$year + 1900`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex-free alternative:

```
d2int <- as.integer(dates$date2)
dates[["date2n"]] <- as.character(d2int + ifelse(d2int > 18, 1900, 2000))
dates
  date1 date2 date2n
1  2015    98   1998
2  1998    00   2000
3  2000    18   2018
4  1991    92   1992
5  2015    89   1989
6  1998    18   2018
7  2000    19   1919
8  1991    NA   <NA>
```

Where:

```
dates <- data.frame(
  date1=c("2015","1998","2000","1991"),
  date2=c("98","00","18","92", "89", "18", "19", "NA"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lubridate` and try something like :

Input:

```
dates <- data.frame(date1=c("2015","1998","2000","1991", "1991", "1991"),
                    date2=c("98","00","18","92", "88", NA))
```

use:

```
dates %>%
  mutate(date2 = as.integer(date2)) %>%
  mutate(date3 = if_else(date2+2000 > year(today()), date2+1900, date2+2000))
```

which gives:

```
  date1 date2 date3
1  2015    98  1998
2  1998     0  2000
3  2000    18  2018
4  1991    92  1992
5  1991    88  1988
6  1991    NA    NA
```

p.s. added two rows to the input data to show how this handles `NA` values